# Pandas DataFrame constructor not properly called

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

as a beginner I am trying this tutorial...

I cannot see, why I am getting error

```
DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

The code I am using is:

```
from surprise import KNNBasic
import pandas as pd
from surprise import Dataset
from surprise import Reader


# Kim rated Star Wars with 1 stars
# Tim rated Star Wars with 5 stars; Tim did no further ratings
movies = ['Star Wars', 'Star Wars', 'GOT', 'GOT', 'South Park', 'South Park',
          'Harry Potter', 'Harry Potter']
rating = [1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 3, 2, 5]
users = ['Kim', 'Tim', 'John', 'Timmy', 'Julian', 'Kim', 'Jimmy', 'Kim'] 


rating_dict = {'user': users,
               'item': movies,
               'rating': rating}

def FriendRecommender(user):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=rating_dict)
    reader = Reader(rating_scale = (1,5))
    data = Dataset.load_from_df(df[['user', 'item', 'rating']], reader)

    trainset = data.build_full_trainset()
    sim_options = {
            'name': 'cosine',
            'user_based': True
            }

    algo = KNNBasic(sim_options)
    algo.fit(trainset)

    uid = trainset.to_inner_uid(user)
    pred = algo.get_neighbors(uid, 3)

    for i in pred: 
        print(trainset.to_raw_uid(i))

FriendRecommender('Tim')
```

I assume something goes wrong in this line:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=rating_dict)
```

I looked into this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html and tried different variations of the code, but I cannot find the cause of the error.

Any of you have an idea?

Would be great :-/

Thanks

Comment: The line `df = pd.DataFrame(data=rating_dict)` works for me with the sample data in your script, so the error would appear to be somewhere else. The error traceback should allow you to identify the offending line ...

Comment: Which python and pandas version are you using?

Comment: He guys, thanks. Christmas solved the problem. Just tried again and now it works. Dont know what the problem was. Thanks anyway.